# Send a pickled dataframe as a file to FastAPI route

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-requests, fastapi, pydantic

I would like to post a pickled dataframe file into a FastAPI route. However, I keep getting an error. Could anyone suggest how to fix my scripts?

This is interesting for me since I would like to preserve the dataframe column types & details. Therefore, posting the dataframe directly to a route is not an option as those details & types would be lost after JSONification.

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File

app = FastAPI(debug=True)

@app.post("/luminex_file/")
async def handle_luminex_data(file: bytes = File(...)):
    df = pd.read_pickle(io.BytesIO(file))
    return {"file_size": len(file), "df": df}
```

request.py

```
files = {'file': open('dataframe.pickle', 'rb')}
response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/luminex_file/", files=files)
```

Comment: Show us the error that you are getting.

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing both the data and the resulting error message.  Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.